# How to select people who has multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I want to select people who has 2 values (activate & recurring) in the table for example,

table :: **tbl_transactions**

| id | name | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | activate |
| 2 | John | recurring |
| 3 | Salah | activate |
| 4 | Bill | activate |
| 5 | Bill | recurring |
| 6 | Bill | recurring |

**Expected result,**

| id | name | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | activate |
| 2 | John | recurring |
| 4 | Bill | activate |
| 5 | Bill | recurring |
| 6 | Bill | recurring |

Please help. I have been spent for an hour to fix this.

Really thanks.

Comment: Are you required to filter out users with only 2 "activate" entries or users with only 2 "recurring" entries?

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I edited my question. I need people who has 'activate' & 'recurring'. Who has only 1 will not be in the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the `action` values for each user `name` and check if the array is `2` long (since you only need 2 actions) and contains `['activate', 'recurring']` (since you only need these values)

```
SELECT t.id, t.name FROM tbl_transactions t
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        ARRAY_AGG(action) AS actions
    FROM tbl_transactions
    GROUP BY name
) user_actions ON t.name = user_actions.name 
                  AND ARRAY_LENGTH(actions, 1) = 2
                  AND ARRAY['activate', 'recurring']::VARCHAR[] @> actions
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2cdb0a75fe2e8887c7bfbfccf75d89c5)

Answer (score 0):

here is a query for selecting only names appearing twice:

```
select t.* 
from t 
  join (select name, count(*) 
        from t 
        having count(*) = 2
       ) c on t.name = c.name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will be as below. Check [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b91805/1). You can use count distinct action to count distinct action value check it is greater than 1.

```
select a.* from tbl_transactions a join 
(select name, count(*) from tbl_transactions group by name having count(distinct action) > ) b 
on a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `bool_or()` window function for this:

```
with complete_check as (
  select id, name, action,
         bool_or(action = 'recurring') over w as has_recurring,
         bool_or(action = 'activate') over w as has_activate
    from tbl_transactions
  window w as (partition by name)
)
select id, name, action
  from complete_check
 where has_recurring and has_activate;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e7ef14c0a44bb297d58727be3dc40c02)*